# Jmeter: How to handle CSRF token from child URL which is not avialable while recording

Tags: jmeter, csrf

I have to use Jmeter to perform load testing for a website.For this I have to record the login page and play back with real loads from CSV file.The website uses CSRF token for login.

While play back the recorded URLS using HTTPs Script recorder,this "/xyz/j_spring_security_check" calls\spawns an URL,/xyz/login.html(This URL is not available in the recorded http requests but could see in the view results tree,that is why I termed this as "calls\spawns",Please correct me with right term ), which generates the CSRF token and session ID.

The /xyz/j_spring_security_check later uses the CSRF token,session token,Username and password to login.
Now the problem is since the URL is called internally,I couldn't postprocess CSRF token from the /xyz/login.html URL.

Please help me to know,how to get the CSRF token which is part of response body of  internally called URL and not available in the recorded http requests.
p.s:I know how to extract the CSRF token from the request response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar, I had included "HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier" and as well as removed off the Different call made on the Child Window. Just enabled the Save/Submit action of the Child window.

This worked for my scenario where a user had Search for a specific value in a child window.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It was due to view results tree size capacity. Increase the view results tree size in Jmeter properties like this:

```
view.results.tree.max_size = 0.
```

All the value you will start to see in view results tree listener. All the tokens and all will be printing.